# Sharing buttons in Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, sharing, pinterest, magnific-popup

I'm hoping to add sharing buttons (Pinterest to start) to each image within a gallery without having to go in and manually include URLs etc. for each individual image/entry. There is plenty of instruction to be had when it comes to including this functionality for other lightboxes--most notably in conjunction with a specific CMS; and I have been reviewing those instructions, as well as w3 resources and other stackoverflow.com entries--with the hope that I could put something together. I'd like to place the share buttons en lieu of the counter. Thus far I've failed. I did have one attempt that resulted in the button being displayed, however the script did not acknowledge the path for the image for a successful "pin." Subsequent attempts at including a "Pin It" button have simply broken Magnific.

Currently, I have:

```
tCounter:
'<a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F  
%2Fgeraldmurai.com&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwindow.location.href&  
description=Aloha!%20Thank%20you%20for%20Pinning!" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-  
config="none" >
<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>'}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: One source I've been referencing for acknowledging the URL of the image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of adding a button, one of the easiest:

```
$('.image-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeBtnInside: false,
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',

        image: {
            verticalFit: true,
            titleSrc: function(item) {

                        var caption = item.el.attr('title');

                        var pinItURL = "http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/";

                        // Refer to http://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/
                        pinItURL += '?url=' + 'http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/';
                        pinItURL += '&media=' + item.el.attr('href');
                        pinItURL += '&description=' + caption;


                        return caption + ' &middot; <a class="pin-it" href="'+pinItURL+'" target="_blank"><img src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a>';
            }
        },


    gallery: {
      enabled: true 
    }, 
    callbacks: {
      open: function() {
        this.wrap.on('click.pinhandler', '.pin-it', function(e) {

          window.open(e.currentTarget.href, "intent", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=yes,width=550,height=420,left=" + (window.screen ? Math.round(screen.width / 2 - 275) : 50) + ",top=" + 100);


          return false;
        });
      },
      beforeClose: function() {
       this.wrap.off('click.pinhandler');
      }
    }

});
```

http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/hutrb

Comment: Thanks!

I've given it a go, (reimplemented original Counter code and placed/modified the above for the gallery call in the html) but I must be doing something wrong because I'm still just getting a broken script.

Comment: view-source:geraldmurai.com/build2/index2.php

Comment: How can you use this code to embed the pin it button in the top right corner of the image and not in the caption? Works brilliantly otherwise. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if someone is still interested...although the answer that Dimitry gave is correct, he forgot to mention that you have to change few things:

```
pinItURL += '?url=' + 'http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/';
pinItURL += '&media=' + item.el.attr('href');
```

First line

```
 pinItURL += '?url=' + '***add here your own website***';
```

Second line I had to add again the name of my website to make the all thing work:

```
pinItURL += '&media=**add here the name of you website plus /**' + item.el.attr('href');
```

Hope it helps someone. Thank you Dmitry ;)

Answer (score 0):

The media URL should point to the lightbox image not a website URL +  image URL.

Full url is located in attr('href') for each of the images.