# Magnific-popup adding social buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, magnific-popup

I try to use Magnific Popup for some feature. And I have faced with a problem. I added a button 'download' below image. But also I need to add block of social buttons to share this image like this: 
[image]

How can I do it?

My code is:

```
<script>

        $('.popup-link').magnificPopup({
          type: 'image',
          image: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
            '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar" style="text-align:center;">'+
            '<div class="mfp-title"></div>'+
            '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="original">Download</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>',
        },
          tLoading: 'Loading image ...',
          gallery:{enabled:true}
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095803/sharing-buttons-in-magnific-popup?rq=1

Comment: @Natrium yeah, thank you!  but what about FB, for example?